# Jupyter shows plot with and without plt.show() but with an addition of extra line

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I wanted to plot the histogram of horsepower to see what the distribution of horsepower looks like

[This is the dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nainQ.png)

The expected plot is shown irrespective of using plt.show().

But without using the plt.show() function a strange line is shown at the top along with the plot i.e

> Text(0.5, 1.0, 'horsepower bins').

**I want to ask why is this strange behaviour What does the line mean at the top of the plot?**

[With plt.show()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ei0l.png)

[Without plt.show()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MREcY.png)

Comment: `plt.title("horsepower bins");`.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.